# Error: /bin/sh: line 21: : No such file or directory

Tags: bash

When I run the command `sudo bash ~/ol_code_hosting/fedora.sh ~/ol_code_hosting/all_packages.txt` to the following bash shell script (I have run bash commands via this script within the docker terminal):

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo service docker restart
docker rm -f container_fedora
docker image rm -f fedora:latest
sudo docker pull fedora
sudo docker run -itd --name container_fedora fedora:latest
sudo docker exec container_fedora /bin/sh -c '

#dnf install dnf
#dnf clean all
#dnf check-update
#dnf upgrade
echo "outside1"
tmpfile=$(mktemp)
echo "outside2"

while IFS= read -r package; do
    echo "inside loop"
    if dnf info "$package" >"$tmpfile"
    then
        echo "Processing $package"
        cat "$tmpfile" >>fedora_log.txt
    else
        printf "No package info for $package"
        printf "%s\n" "$package" >>packages_not_in_fedora.txt
    fi
done <"$1"

rm -f "$tmpfile"
exit'

sudo docker cp container_fedora:/fedora_log.txt ./fedora_log.txt
```

Output received:

```
container_fedora
Untagged: fedora:latest
Untagged: fedora@sha256:2c5b21348e9b2a0b4c49bd5013be6d406be8594831aba21043393fcfba7252e0
Deleted: sha256:98ffdbffd20736862c8955419ef7db69849d715131717697007c3e51f22915a5
Deleted: sha256:811f92a7a340873e7fef337f3f3cab4f353f24ca0b303ed0f46b00917e262a7b
Using default tag: latest
latest: Pulling from library/fedora
e1deda52ffad: Pull complete 
Digest: sha256:2c5b21348e9b2a0b4c49bd5013be6d406be8594831aba21043393fcfba7252e0
Status: Downloaded newer image for fedora:latest
docker.io/library/fedora:latest
9909e072f6fe41b2a8909b414f199ddeadaaa8a5daac70e3d0f765726e288302
outside1
/bin/sh: line 21: : No such file or directory
outside2
Error: No such container:path: container_fedora:/fedora_log.txt
```

I am at a loss to know such an error message is being displayed everytime. Could someone help. Thank you very much!

Comment: Looks like the trouble line is probably `done <"$1"` and the shell is telling you there's no such file as the empty string.

Comment: @SottoVoce Oh! Though, I did check the file : ./all_packages.txt and it seems to contain all the packages that I intend to.

Comment: I think the script/string that's being passed to `sh -c` does not register the `all_packages.txt` file as a command-line argument.  As a result `$1` is empty.

Comment: Aah I see. Do you think a workaround would be to copy all_packages.txt to docker container first?

Comment: Could you take the `#1` out of the singe quotes, and then start them back up? `done <"'$1'"`

Comment: @frabjous or just add `sh "$1"` to the line with `exit'` (i.e. change that line to `exit' sh "$1"`).  That will pass the outer bash script's first arg to the `/bin/sh -c '...'` script.  Note that you need to provide a dummy $0 argument (e.g. I used "sh") if you want to pass args to `sh -c`.